# Microsoft SQL Constraint - limit driver from forbidden site

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, constraints, check-constraints

I'm using Microsoft SQL server 2008 and I need to create a constraint that will prevent a [Tx] from being created/updated if the [Driver] is not allowed to either the source [Shipper] or destination [Consignee] site.

**Tables:**

- Drivers (holds typical driver info)
- Shipper/Consignee (source/destination site - holds locations the driver goes from/to)
- DriverForbiddenSite (holds sites the driver is not allowed to)
- Schedule (hold driver, and when)
- Tx (a transaction has source site{shipper}, destination site {consignee}, cargo, schedule)

Here is a query that will show any record that violates the rule:

```
select * from DriverForbiddenSite dfs
    join Schedule sch on dfs.driverId=sch.driverId
    join Tx tx on sch.scheduleId=tx.scheduleId
    left join Shipper shi on shi.shipperId=tx.shipperId
    left join Consignee con on con.consigneeId=tx.consigneeId
where dfs.transloadLocationId=shi.transloadLocationId or dfs.transloadLocationId=con.transloadLocationId
```

How would be best to prevent Tx's from being created if the Driver is not allowed on the Site?

Thanks

Comment: Yeah. I am sure the question is supposed to make sense for you.

Comment: I'm sorry you don't understand the question. I need help creating a constraint. I welcome your feedback on what you don't understand?

Comment: Define a instead of trigger for the same purpose.

Comment: An instead of trigger is a good idea. I'll look into that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Full credit goes to Rahul. I was trying to solve this by using a constraint when instead I should use a trigger. The "instead of insert" and "instead of update" trigger will allow me to check if the driver is allowed on the Tx before it inserts/updates a Tx record.

Thanks Rahul, feel free to enter your own answer and I'll accept that instead.